# Как получить промежутки plt.hist()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, гистограммы

У меня есть список данных:

```py
x_list_repeats = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 19, 22, 22, 25, 27, 27, 27, 28, 29, 31, 31, 32, 32, 33, 34, 36, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 41, 41, 42, 42, 45, 47, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 59, 61, 61, 63, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 68, 68, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 72, 73, 77, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 82, 84, 84, 86, 86, 86, 89, 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 92, 93, 94, 97, 99]
```

Я на основе этого списка строю гистограмму используя matplotlib.

```py
plt.hist(x_list_repeats, bins=amountOfIntervals)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Как получить те же промежутки блоков гистограммы, которые рассчитывает функция `plt.hist()` при определенном количестве `amountOfIntervals`?

Желательно получить промежутки в виде списка

[image: На картинке отметил красными стрелками промежутки, которые я ищю]

Comment: может `bar` попробовать использовать - `ax.bar(x, y, 1 if bin_size == 1 else 0.9)`

Comment: @Zhihar а что такое  `x, y` ?

Comment: x - массив номеров каналов (бинов), y - массив значения каналов (бинов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1.

```
x = np.random.normal(size=100)
hist_data=plt.hist(x,bins=30)
print(hist_data[1])
```

результат:

```
[-2.179977   -2.00165174 -1.82332647 -1.64500121 -1.46667595 -1.28835068
 -1.11002542 -0.93170016 -0.75337489 -0.57504963 -0.39672437 -0.2183991
 -0.04007384  0.13825142  0.31657669  0.49490195  0.67322721  0.85155248
  1.02987774  1.208203    1.38652826  1.56485353  1.74317879  1.92150405
  2.09982932  2.27815458  2.45647984  2.63480511  2.81313037  2.99145563
  3.1697809 ]
```

Вариант 2:

```
hist_dataN, hist_binsN = np.histogram(x,bins=30)
print(hist_binsN)
```

Результат тождественен предыдущему. И там и там получаем границы интервалов.